# Copying files while there is enough space in linux bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I want to create simple bash script which will copy data files from source directory to tmpfs ramdrive. I need this script to be time-effective so it is not an option to try to do copy and check result code of copy command ( I assume copy command will start copying and fail only when there is no space. I want to avoid starting copy when there is not enough space). Here is pseudocode:

```
for filename in /data/*.dat; do
    bname="$(basename $filename)"
    ramname="/ramd/$bname"
    if there is not enough space for $filename on ramdrive then
        break
    cp $filename $ramname
done
```

Can you please suggest a replacement for the if-break statement.

Comment: One more note: source files are on slow media and are pretty big. This is why I want to avoid starting copy when there is not enough free space on the target dir.

Comment: You may want to check [`stat`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/stat/) command. It has options for file size. For free size in file-system, I am not sure whether stat is more useful, or parsing [`df`](http://www.unix.com/man-pages.php?section=0&os=Linux&query=df) is easier.

Comment: @igor.sol: did the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with `POSIX` defined options for [df - report free disk space](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/df.html) and [du - estimate file space usage](http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1posix/du/), the former with the `-P` flag for reporting the free space available on the system and parsing out only block size with `awk` and doing the same for the file with the `-k` flag in `du`.

```
availMem=$(df -P "$ramname" | awk 'END{print $4}')
fileSize=$(du -k "$filename" | awk '{print $1}')

if (( fileSize > availMem )); then
    break
fi
```

(or) a `POSIX`-ly integer comparison without `bash` as

```
if [ "$fileSize" -gt "$availMem" ]; then
    break
fi
```

You can also throw in a `printf` just before the `break` for a debug purose,

```
printf "Requesting %s for copy when there is only %s left\n" "$fileSize" "$availMem"
```

Comment: Thank you for answer @Inian, unfortunately I had no chance to try this yet. I will mark it as the correct answer when I will be sure it works.